# Hibernate: Eager Fetch Only Specified Fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Is there a way to specify the only fields to be eagerly fetched in hibernate/JPA @ManyToOne - FetchType.EAGER?

Something like:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, eagerFields={"id","name"})
private Company company;
```

Comment: No, and you usually shouldn't set `EAGER` on default, because you can write the queries to use `FETCH` for eager retrieval, but you can't write them to use lazy-loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPA 2.0 specification does not define the possiblity you are trying to achieve as `@ManyToOne` annotation is defined as follows (see [section 11.1.26 of the JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec)):

```
public @interface ManyToOne {
    Class targetEntity() default void.class;
    CascadeType[] cascade() default {};
    FetchType fetch() default EAGER;
    boolean optional() default true;
}
```

What you can do to achieve eager loading only for selected fields, is possible if you specify `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` for the fields of `Company`entity you want to load lazily; **BUT** that is not encouraged for fields other than association fields because it depends on the mercy of the provider implementation as the following extract shows:

> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that data must be eagerly
>   fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched
>   lazily when it is first accessed. The implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the
>   LAZY strategy hint has been specified. In particular, lazy fetching might only be available for Basic
>   mappings for which property-based access is used.