# How to retrieve only specific field of related entity in Springboot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have two related entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "family_events")
public class FamilyEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "family_event_date")
    private Date familyEventDate;

    private String family;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "family_event_type_id")
    private FamilyEventType familyEventType;

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public Date getFamilyEventDate() {
        return familyEventDate;
    }

    public FamilyEventType getFamilyEventType() {
        return familyEventType;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and family_event_types:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "family_event_types")
public class FamilyEventType {
    @Id
    private char id;

    @Column(name = "family_event_type")
    private String familyEventType;

    public String getFamilyEventType() {
        return familyEventType;
    }

    public char getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
}
```

And Im using this query in my repository class in order to retrieve some specific family_events records:

```
public interface FamilyEventRepository extends JpaRepository<FamilyEvent, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM family_events WHERE family_event_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<FamilyEvent> getFamilyEventsBetween(String startDate, String endDate);
}
```

However when I get the results, my records include the familyEventType of family_event_types entity. And I only want to retrieve the Id of that related entity (no more fields).

How can I do that? Do I have to create a wrapper? I would like to use only native queries, but if its not possible, then that's ok.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` on top of `FamilyEventType` fields? Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36977540/10367370

Comment: @Vimukthi Hi, I did it this way 
atBasic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    atId
    private char id;

    atBasic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    atColumn(name = "family_event_type")
    private String familyEventType; and still 

And Im still getting the field familyEventType(String) when using my query

Comment: Your FamilyEvent has a mapping to FamilyEventType instances, which would have to be fully mapped when using the basic queries. If you want to control and only partially fetch attributes, you'll probably have to use JPA queries (though native SQL queries may work) and specify load and fetch graphs to define which properties you want built into your entity and which should be lazily loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978349/496099 as you'll probably want to use a fetchgraph to define exactly what you want to fetch in both entities

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the query. You wrote

`SELECT * FROM family_events WHERE family_event_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2`
This returns all the fields. If you want only the id then it should be
`SELECT id FROM family_events WHERE family_event_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2`.

Then you must also change the return type of

```
 ArrayList<FamilyEvent> getFamilyEventsBetween(String startDate, String endDate);
```

to `ArrayList<String>`.
And one more thing, you will always get the familyEventType of family_event_types entity irrespective of FetchType while using `select *`. Because the FetchType.LAZY in JPA is an ORM-level directive. JPA's directives won't influence what's fetched from the database in the case of Native queries.
I don't recommend you to use a native query here, but if you insist you have to specify all the columns you want to be fetched in your query.